Plasma Railgun Toroids
In my world, the base kinetic weapon is a chemical railgun, with both gunpowder(or an equivalent) and electromagnetic rails propelling the rounds. A second round type is very hot burning chemicals with pressurized gas, forming plasma, which the metal rails used to accelerate the bullets then accelerate. However, forming a toroid would be best for range. Would the rails have to be altered or more added to mold the plasma into a toroid (which is the most stable plasma shape, as found by project MARAUDER) or would it just form? The biggest question is whether I can form a toroid shape by altering the magnetic fields and not adding a rod in the middle of the barrel

(a) Why do you believe torroids would be better? Please [edit] to provide a brief explanation and citation. (b) Your barrel seems to be doing a lot (chemical slugs, metal rails, and plasma rails) - I assume we're ignoring the complexities of that. (c) The power needed to rail plasma is so great that it makes me wonder why you're trying to rail plasma. (d) No, the plasma won't form a torroid naturally. It needs to be formed under magnetic confinement that way. (e) You're operating under Clarke's third law - why such a small detail?

The idea is to use the metal rails for the railgun to accelerate the plasma, which, as they found in project MARAUDER, is most stable in toroid form. The chemical propellant is to heat the gas into plasma or further accelerate the metal rounds

(a) Clarifications go into your post, not comments. Never trust people to read comments. (b) It certainly makes a lot of sense that Philips Labs mad torroidal plasma as Project Maurader's intent was to make a coaxial rail gun, meaning there was a ling of magnets along a central line to the tube. No rail gun in service that I'm aware of uses this design (could be wrong about that). So, you're trying to build a coaxial gun.

I’m voting to close this question because the latest edit has made the question a Real World engineering question and not a worldbuilding quesiton.

I don't think a combo weapon like this would work. A conventional gun has a muzzle velocity that is limited by the energy per unit mass of the explosive. Your bullet will not go faster than the explosion that is pushing it. You can use the bullet to compress and heat hydrogen, which can drive a second bullet a bit faster. I had wondered whether we could get escape velocity on Mars with one of these.
A rail gun uses an expanding magnetic field to drive the bullet. The magnetic field has no rest mass, so there is no clear upper limit like a chemically-driven weapon. However, you have to have a sliding contact (the rails) which makes them tricky to build and operate. Someone I worked with who had worked on railguns described a railgun as 'a machine that throws its breech twelve feet into the ground if there is anyone over the rank of Major watching'. A plasma gun is a similar-ish thing - you can pass pulsed power through your driver material and get energy densities beyond what you can do with chemistry.
To summarise: we have chemical guns with a pretty fixed limit to the muzzle velocity. There are pulsed power guns with no upper limit on the muzzle velocity, but these are heavy and unreliable. Some combo weapon would have all the disadvantages, and none of the advantages.

All you would have to add would be batteries (which can be minimized and very efficient in setting), and two rails in the barrel

Rather more than a battery. The Marx generator that I used to work with was the size of a four bedroom house and moved on two sets of rails. And if something goes wrong, then all the electric energy gets dumped straight into your apparatus.

As someone with only a vague idea of how railguns work - is there any possible benefit to using a chemical explosion for the initial acceleration, before the magnetic field takes over? Would it let you shorten the rails and reduce weight and power requirements?

@user111403 It is hard to see how. Flames, sparks, and plasmas conduct electricity. rather well. It would be possible to use pulsed power to propel gases, but they would've to be pretty well insulated from the electromagnetic bit or they would short it out. It might be possible to do the equivalent of blowing smoke rings with ionised plasmas. I don't know whether those would travel in a vacuum, but I doubt they would go very far in air.

@user111403 Quite the opposite, really. Stepping away from "guns", but still looking at "electromagnets vs chemical power", you have engines vs motors. An electric motor delivers maximum torque at 0RPM, while a chemical engine deliver maximum torque at high RPM. (This is why Hybrid cars use their electric motors at low speeds, and their engines at high speeds). Or, in other words, you would get more advantage from using a magnetic field for the initial acceleration, and then the chemical explosive to kick things up to its top speed than the other way around. But that top speed is then lower.

@Chronocidal, one of the problems with railguns is electrical arcs as the projectile initially contacts the rails.  The faster you can inject the projectile, the less arcing there is.  (You can't start dumping electricity into the railgun with the projectile stationary and contacting the rails -- if you do, you get an arc welder, not a gun.)

The only way to get a toroid would be to have a specially shaped barrel on the device. Toroids don't just form naturally unless shaped specifically. An example of this is blowing bubbles underwater or blowing smoke rings - if you just blow out, you won't get a toroid, you'll just get a puff of smoke/bubble most of the time. Instead if you shape your lips just right and add some pushing action to increase the rotational speed in the centre (done with the tongue in smoke rings), you should get the shape consistently.
For a gun, I would guess that the easiest way would be to have a barrel with the shape already in it - i.e. a tube with another smaller tube inside to shape the plasma.
Like in the comments, I don't think using plasma as a weapon is practical.  Unless you are in space, interaction with an atmosphere would rapidly degrade any plasma you could generate, and a torus would likely have to travel quite slowly to maintain shape. You would need tons and tons of power to generate a plasma cannon that wouldn't be practical outside of a large battleship sort of object. Of course, you can get away with this in SciFi by having hand-wavy power sources.
I'm at a loss as to why you would have both chemical and magnetic acceleration of the railgun. The chemical acceleration specifically is not rail-gun at all - the term derives from the rails used to hold the projectile while accelerating on the magnetic impulse. The projectile contacts both rails to complete the circuit and make it into an electromagnet. How adding an explosive would improve this, I don't see.

The idea is that they can’t get a railgun to accelerate the bullet to the speeds it needs to go in order to penetrate armor, which is its job, so they put chemicals in as well, also allowing the cartridges to be the same size as the plasma, which have to superheat the gas with chemicals

@Ike So a mixed round capability using the railgun for plasma and chemical for bullets? In that case you would need extremely good engineering and materials - the chemical propellents will destroy the magnetic/plasma forming capabilities quite quickly I think. If the railgun can't accelerate the bullet fast enough, then it also won't be able to accelerate the plasma to anywhere near the speeds needed.

Everything (chemicals and rails) is used to propel both types of rounds, with hotter chemicals used for creation of plasma in those rounds.
